# Pass data from one page to another in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was asked following scenario in an interview.

I need to pass data from one page to another in .net web forms or MVC. But i cannot use following.
1. session 
2. Hidden Fields 
3. cookies
4. view state 
5. app state 
6. query string

Any another way????

Comment: Dumb interview question, why bother...? There are some ways to do it, but I'm not sure it fits this website to answer it.

Comment: You can use the HTTP request body or HTTP request header.

Comment: @Romoku can you provide a short example?

Comment: It depends on whether you want the request to originate from the client or the server. Additionally the implementation is different between MVC, WebForms, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this for reference ,There are various method but this
>   comes in mind at this time.

```
 //For saving in cache
     WebCache.Set("test", "any data comes here", 10, false); // Cache the value for 10 minutes

    //Retrieving the data
        string test = WebCache.Get("test");
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))
        {
         //get test value here
        }
        else
        {
          //No data msg
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Public Properties` to get data from source page to target page:

**Source Page**

```
public String MyValue
{
get
{
    return TexBoxMyValue.Text;
}
}
```

**On the target page**, add a `@PreviousPageType` page directive that points to the source page, and access value using `PreviousPage.`

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>

Label1.Text = PreviousPage.MyValue;
```

Also see this: http://www.nullskull.com/a/10400710/eight-different-ways-to-transfer-data-from-one-page-to-another-page.aspx